# how do I add a project or template type in the monodevelop?

Tags: ubuntu, project, monodevelop

how do I add a project type in the monodevelop?
so I have the possibility to create a project from that template.

im using ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: https://github.com/xunit/xamarinstudio.xunit/tree/7.0/MonoDevelop.XUnit/templates This extension contains its own templates, which you can take a look.

Comment: sorry i did not understand or i did not express myself very well
I have a folder with a sln project. which has a standard design tamplate.
so whenever I create a new project, I'd like it to be on the projects screen.
sorry for my English.
I use visual studio in my work. in home use only gnu / linux, I would not like to migrate to windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MonoDevelop 7.0 the simplest way is to install the [Template Creator addin](https://lastexitcode.com/blog/2017/11/12/TemplateCreatorForVisualStudioMac/). This can be used to create a project template from an existing project, by right clicking the project, selecting Create Template, entering some metadata, and then the template is available in the New Project dialog.

Otherwise you can create your own [addin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/extending-visual-studio-mac-walkthrough) and registering the project template in the addin's .addin.xml file.

The example below uses the old templating engine file format.

Addin's .addin.xml file:

```
<Extension path = "/MonoDevelop/Ide/ProjectTemplates">
    <ProjectTemplate id = "MonoDevelop.CSharp.ConsoleProject" resource = "ConsoleProject.xpt.xml"/>
</Extension>
```

An example project template file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Template originator   = "Mike Krueger"
          created      = "06/10/2001"
          lastModified = "02/01/2003">

    <!-- Template Header -->
    <TemplateConfiguration>
        <_Name>Console Project</_Name>
        <Category>other/net/general</Category>
        <Icon>md-console-project</Icon>
        <Image id="md-console-project" />
        <LanguageName>C#</LanguageName>
        <_Description>Creates a new C# console project.</_Description>
        <DefaultFilename>ConsoleProject</DefaultFilename>
        <GroupId>md-project-console</GroupId>
    </TemplateConfiguration>

    <!-- Actions -->
    <Actions>
        <Open filename = "Program.cs"/>
    </Actions>

    <!-- Template Content -->
    <Combine name = "${ProjectName}" directory = ".">
        <Options>
            <StartupProject>${ProjectName}</StartupProject>
        </Options>

        <Project name = "${ProjectName}" directory = ".">
            <Options ExternalConsole="True"/>
            <References>
                <Reference type="Package" refto="System, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            </References>
            <Files>
                <File name="Program.cs" AddStandardHeader="True"><![CDATA[using System;

namespace ${Namespace}
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}]]></File>
            <FileTemplateReference TemplateID="CSharpAssemblyInfo" name="AssemblyInfo.cs" />
            </Files>
        </Project>
    </Combine>
</Template>
```

MonoDevelop 7.0 also supports the .NET Core (dotnet) templating engine. That allows you to create a NuGet package (.nupkg) with the template and have that referenced in the .addin.xml file:

```
<Extension path="/MonoDevelop/Ide/Templates">
    <Template
        id="Microsoft.Common.Console.CSharp"
        _overrideName="Console Application"
        _overrideDescription="Creates a new .NET Core console project."
        path="Templates/Microsoft.DotNet.Common.ProjectTemplates.1.x.1.0.0-beta2-20170430-208.nupkg"
        icon="md-netcore-console-project"
        imageId="md-netcore-console-project"
        condition="UseNetCore1x=true"
        category="netcore/app/general"/>
</Extension>
```